# Screenscraping with Python

Tags: python

I am trying to screenscape this screen - [text](https://screenrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other)

This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Base URL for the team rankingsquit()
base_url = "https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other"

# Dates range
start_date = date(2023, 3, 30)
end_date = date(2023, 10, 5)

# CSV file to save data
csv_filename = "team_rankings.csv"

# CSV header
header = ["Date", "Rank", "Team", "Predictive Rank", "Rating"]

# Open CSV file for writing
with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(header)

    # Loop through dates
    current_date = start_date
    while current_date <= end_date:
        # Generate URL for current date
        current_url = f"{base_url}/?{current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"

        print(current_url)

        # Fetch the webpage
        response = requests.get(current_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        # Find the table containing the team rankings
        table = soup.find('table', {'class': 'tr-table datatable scrollable'})

        print(table)

        if table:
            # Extract data from the table rows
            for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
                cols = row.find_all('td')
                rank = cols[0].text.strip()
                team = cols[1].text.strip()
                predictive_rank = cols[2].text.strip()
                rating = cols[3].text.strip()

                # Write data to CSV file
                writer.writerow([current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), rank, team, predictive_rank, rating])

        # Move to the next date
        current_date += timedelta(days=1)

print("Data scraping and saving completed!")
```

All that I get are the default date which is 11/02/2023.  I want all dates between 3/30/23 and 10/5/2023 which are defined in start_date and end_date.  Any suggestions on how to do this?  I am guessing that the filter needs to be changed but I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: I am unable to view the target webpage - I get an `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` DNS error.  Not sure if its the link, or if my ISP is having an issue with it.  My initial guess, as it always is with similar posts here on SO, is that the page content is dynamically loaded using JavaScript, which means using `requests` is not sufficient.  You will need to use `Selenium`. `PlayWright` or a similar tool to open a browser instance, and then you can scrape the data after the JavaScript renders it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure why my link does not work but https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other?date=2023-11-02 is definitely a valid url.  Thanks for trying. Do you know if I can edit my initial question?

Comment: You should be able to edit your own question.  There is an `edit` link at the bottom of the question, to the left of your name info, between Share and Close

Answer (score 0):

Your url pattern of `current_url = f"{base_url}/?{current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"` is incorrect.

https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other/?2023-04-28

You are missing the key of that date parameter value which is `date`. so my example above should actually be:

https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other/?date=2023-04-28

Secondly, if you are scraping `<table>` tags, just let pandas do the parsing.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta


# Dates range
start_date = date(2023, 3, 30)
end_date = date(2023, 10, 5)

base_url = 'https://www.teamrankings.com/mlb/ranking/predictive-by-other'
current_date = start_date
dfs = []
while current_date <= end_date:
    print(f"{current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")
    url = f"{base_url}/?date={current_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}"
    temp_df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    temp_df['Date'] = current_date
    
    dfs.append(temp_df)
    current_date += timedelta(days=1)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index(drop=True)    
csv_filename = "team_rankings.csv"
df.to_csv(csv_filename, index=False)


print("Data scraping and saving completed!")
```